# Creating a wizard-style form spanning multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, wizard, multi-step

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a solution to implement a wizard-style form, which would span multiple models. Of course I did find a few resources but all of them focussed on a single model. I found

1. The [acts_as_wizard](https://github.com/adkron/actsaswizard) plugin
2. Ryan's Railscast on [multi-step forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms)

One more catch in my situation is, the wizard-style of creating stuff is not the only way, which is what I think the plugin and the railscast assume. That is, I could use the wizard style of creating objects in a sequence or create individual objects in an adhoc fashion.

So, I would preferably restrict code to models or modules and not mess with controller code.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm working in the same pattern this week.

I have a multi model wizard, where every step touch a set of models. I did work using "transactions", the old ActiveModel transations, that now is a [gem](https://github.com/qoobaa/transitions).

So basically, my form load always the same view, where i just reload it. this view reload a partial for a specific step. In my wizard all (4) steps are mandatory. so the user is just able to go further if he complete the previous steps. I submit, save the objects that i have to and then move to the next step. If you plan to put one step as review in the end, where you first review what you did and then you apply it. i would recommend to do one single form where you hide and unhide the steps. You can do it easily with javascript.

Comment: I tend to avoid Javascript as much as possible. Thanks nevertheless! May have to go with JS if I don't find a Rails solution.

Comment: humm, but with js is easier. You do many divs, where a div has a step, hide all steps and just show the step where the user is. in the end you submit this single form.. it works greats if you don't have to keep steep between steps.